# Is this function correspondence reversible?

Tags: functions

Consider an arbitrary real-valued multivariate function:

$$ y = F(x_1,\dots,x_n) $$

**Define** the following subsidiary function:

$$ G_i(x_1,\dots,x_n) \equiv y - \frac{\partial y}{\partial x_i}x_i $$

So, for any given $F(\cdot)$ I can find $G_i(\cdot)$.

For example, say $y = x_1^a x_2^{1-a}$. Then,

$$ G_1 \equiv (1-a)x_1^a x_2^{1-a} $$

$$ G_2 \equiv ax_1^a x_2^{1-a} $$

The question is, can I find $F(\cdot)$ from **one and only one** given $G_i(\cdot)$?

If I know all $G_i(\cdot)$, things are a bit easier. In the above example, the function is homogeneous of degree $k=1$. Therefore, it follows that

$$ ky = \sum^n_{i=1} \frac{\partial y}{\partial x_i}x_i $$

from where we can find $F(\cdot)$ given **all** $G_i(\cdot)$.

My attemps.

1. The main equation is
   $$ G_i(x_1,\dots,x_n) \equiv y - \frac{\partial y}{\partial x_i}x_i $$

If we rearrange, we get:

$$ G_i(x_1,\dots,x_n) \equiv y\left(1 - \frac{\partial y}{\partial x_i}\frac{x_i}{y}\right) = y\left(1 - \frac{\partial \ln y}{\partial \ln x_i}\right) $$

Not sure how to proceed.

2. Distribute the partial (is this even legit?):

$$ G_i(x_1,\dots,x_n)\partial x_i \equiv y\partial x_i - x_i\partial y $$

Which if we integrate, is almost the same as the [integration by parts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_parts) formula, but with different sign.

Answer (score 1):

Knowing only one of the $G_i$ does not give you enough information to reconstruct $F$.

For example, if $F = ax_1 + bx_2$ then

$G_1 = F - ax_1 = bx_2 \\ G_2 = F - bx_2 = ax_1$

To reconstruct $F$ you need to know both $G_1$ and $G_2$.

Comment: So basically, one counterexample shows is not possible in general, is it? Unless some more information is given. Clearly homogeneity degree is not enough either.